# how to load kernel config files when using jupyter console?

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-console

In `IPython` you can create a profile file `foo` and load it by running `ipython --profile=foo`.
Is it possible to do the same with `jupyter console`?

I am not interested in loading a `jupyter console` config file but a kernel specific config file, i.e. I am wondering if there is a command like (or similar to) `jupyter console --kernel=python3 --profile=foo`, where `foo` is a config file referred to the kernel `python3`.